# How to use default column value for the rowtype variable in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table and a procedure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
info TEXT);

create or replace function test() returns void as
$$
declare
  v_row test_table%ROWTYPE;
begin
  v_row.info := 'test';
  insert into test_table values (v_row.*);
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

select test();

ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

How to use default value for the v_row.id field? I know I could write

```
insert into test_table (info) values (v_row.info);
```

But in my real case I have a lot of such tables with many columns and I really want to avoid enumerating all the columns in the insert statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing `insert into test_table values (v_row.*);` you actually force postgres to insert NULL value into the `id` column.

You will need to run such code - either in application

```
v_row.id := nextval( 'mysequence' );
```

.. or in trigger

```
IF NEW.id IS NULL THEN
    NEW.id := nextval( 'mysequence' );
END IF;
```

Comment: I was hoping for something like

    v_row.id = default;

or

    v_row.id = test_table.id.default;

But neither of them works.

Answer (score 0):

You can check, if Postgresql have a SEQUENCE for this column and then, if this column have a DEFAULT value set. In `psql` try:

```
\d+ test_table
```

You have to see somethink like this:

```
id    | integer                     | default nextval('test_table_id_seq'::regclass) |
```

If there is not a `default nextval('somethink')`, then you have to check, if there is sequnence for this column:

```
\ds+
```

You have to see somethink like this:

```
 public | test_table_id_seq | sequence
```

If you will not have a sequence, you have a CREATE it:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE test_table_id_seq;
```

And if you will have not a `default nextval('somethink'), you have use a ALTER TABLE:

```
ALTER TABLE test_table ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('test_table_id_seq');
```

You can find about it some informations here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Perhaps you can understand it, although English is not my native language...

Comment: SERIAL type creates sequence and default value, as you can see, so I do have both. The default value is simply ignored when I use rowtype.* in the insert command.

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry. Then, it is safe to use solution in answer of @filiprem.